# How to keep logstash running even when I logout from the remote server

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am connecting to a remote host via ssh login and running logstash by the following command

```
$./logstash -f first-pipeline.conf
```

However, after I logout from the server, the logstash stops running. How to enable it to keep running even after I logout. Thanks.

Comment: Run it with nohup > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10408816/how-do-i-use-the-nohup-command-without-getting-nohup-out

Comment: Hi can you provide the command to run it in nohup? I tried 
nohup ./logstash -f first-pipeline.conf. 

But didn't work

Comment: ```$nohup logstash -f ~/logstash/pipeline.conf &``` but I've also tested and it worked if you're running with the agent argument like so ```$ logstash agent -f ~/logstash/pipeline.conf```. Let me know if running as agent works for you too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach is to use the [`screen` command](https://www.rackaid.com/blog/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/) which can be very useful for this.

First you open your SSH session, then type `screen` at the prompt. That opens a new session in which you can run your logstash command.

When it runs, you simply press `Ctrl+a d` in order to detach your self from that screen and you can safely logout.

Whenever you log back into your SSH session, you enter `screen -r` and you will get back into your previous session where logstash was started.

You can create as many "screens" as you wish to start many different processes at different times.

Also see [this comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20766300/nohup-vs-screen-which-is-better-for-long-running-process) between using `nohup` and `screen`

Answer (score 0):

Just run it as an agent
`$ logstash agent -f ~/logstash/pipeline.conf`

Comment: The "agent" is not a valid parameter in logstash 5.3