# How to run wget In background for an unattended download of files?

Tags: linux, download, wget

How can I download a file unattended using `wget` (for example, I want to download a large ISO file  in the background)?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```
wget -bqc http://path.com/url.iso
```

where:

**-b**: Go to background immediately after startup. If no output file is specified via the -o, output is redirected to wget-log.

**-q**: Turn off Wget's output (saves some disk space)

**-c**: Resume broken download i.e. continue getting a partially-downloaded file. This is useful when you want to finish up a download started by a previous instance of Wget, or by another program.

**Alternative method:**

Use `nohup` like this:

```
nohup wget http://example.com/dvd.iso &
exit
```

[nixCraft](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-run-wget-in-background.html)

Comment: nohup wget http://domain.com/dvd.iso > /dev/null 2>&1 & similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797050/how-to-run-process-as-background-and-never-die

Comment: To see if the process is indeed running after exiting from shell and logging again, type `top` or `htop` command. `jobs -l` does not list the process once exited from the shell and logging again.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with

```
wget http://path.com/url.iso &> wget.log &
```