# NodeJs not staying live in aws

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, bitnami

I have deployed a Bitnami AMI of NodeJS on an AWS micro instance. After starting my node app, everything works fine.

After some time without any activity, the app which is attached to port :3000, seems to shut down. When this happens on refreshing the page my browser gives the message:

```
Network Error (tcp_error) 
A communication error occurred: "Connection refused"
The Web Server may be down, too busy, or experiencing other problems preventing it from responding to requests. You may wish to try again at a later time.
```

The AWS console shows the instance is still running and the Bitnami build still responds with the standard message on port 80.

Comment: How do you launch your NodeJS application inside the instance?

Comment: Good question.  I have been reviewing possible causes and think I traced the problem to the ssh session terminating and taking the node app with it.  I have now started the app using **nohup** and it seems to have stayed up for the last two hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we discussed in comments, the problem was binding the node process to SSH session.

You can use `nohup` or `screen` to launch the node process in an instance not bound to session. 
I suggest using `screen` because the function of returning to launched instance is essential for maintenance/updating.

Related: [How to run process as background and never die](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797050/how-to-run-process-as-background-and-never-die)

Related: [Command-Line Interface tool to run node as a service](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever)

Answer (score 2):

Forever (https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever) is also a useful tool for this kind of thing, and it gives you a little more control than nohup or screen.

Comment: Forever is already included in the Bitnami Node.js stack. Bitnami recommends this tool for managing the services.

Answer (score 0):

Besides configuring an EC2-instance you can also use the PaaS-solution of AWS, namely Elastic Beanstalk. They have also support for Node.js and it's super easy to deploy your apps using this service.