# Unable to start Mesos slave on single node cluster

Tags: mesos

From what I know I am able to set up Mesos master, slave, zookeeper, marathon on a single node.

But once I execute the command to start mesos-master and after that I am trying to start mesos-slave as well but I don't have any way to continue to execute other commands else where. I have to stop the running and run but the problem is mesos-master already stop running.

[image]

Comment: You can only run one process in the foreground of each shell. So to run the master and slave on a single node, you can either use multiple shells, or use screen/nohup& to launch the mesos-master and slave processes in the background. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797050/how-to-run-process-as-background-and-never-die Another alternative is to install mesos as a system service, so you can run `service mesos-master start` for it to run as a daemon in the background.

Comment: I need to have the configuration file to start run service mesos-master start right? What details should I put inside or ?

Comment: I have use screen to run the master and slave on a single node. It success how do I further continue to start marathon? Is it the same way or?

Answer (score 1):

Don't execute the commands directly from your shell, you want to start all of those components (zookeeper, mesos-master, mesos-slave, and marathon) as services.

/etc/init.d/zookeeper start

start mesos-master

start mesos-slave

start marathon

I forget if zookeeper creates the init script as part of the install for you or not, you may have to find it in the Hadoop docs.

As for the other 3, they all use 'upstart' and you can find the configuration files in /etc/init/

Comment: what if I do not have any configuration files of mesos-master, mesos-slave, marathon ? Where do I find to get the files (as in the steps of the configuration and etc) ?

Comment: You can simply use the command-line parameters if you're running the commands from the shell, or place your configuration options under /etc/default/mesos or /etc/mesos-master, /etc/mesos-slave. For example, `echo zk://10.1.1.10:2181/mesos | sudo tee /etc/mesos/zk`

Comment: The upstart scripts should get created automatically when you install the packages. What OS are you on, how did you install Mesos and Marathon?