# How to start dnx "web" in the background then how to stop it (on ubuntu)?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, asp.net-core-mvc, dnx, kestrel-http-server

how can I start a kestrel server running asp.net 5 in the background on ubuntu.

Usually you kick start the server by typing `dnx web` but this will start a process and you can't go back to shell unless you stop it by typing Ctrl+c

How can I start it in the background and return back to shell? also how to stop it once it is started in the background?

Is there a way to make this start once you start the ubuntu server? like a service for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no out of the box solution for this but you can use something like [nohup](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/nohup-execute-commands-after-you-exit-from-a-shell-prompt.html) to do this. However, you'll have to kill the process in order to terminate it.

Also, see this question: [How to run process as background and never die?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797050/how-to-run-process-as-background-and-never-die)