# Listening a port constantly

Tags: java, daemon

I want to allow a java app to listen a port. I run the required command from a command prompt and it listens to the port and I see `Server is listening on port 7070` as output and command line cannot pass low line. If I close the command prompt, it disconnects and then the port is closed.

Here is relevant code:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

import de.l3s.boilerpipe.document.TextDocument;
import de.l3s.boilerpipe.extractors.ArticleExtractor;
import de.l3s.boilerpipe.sax.BoilerpipeSAXInput;


// Language detect librarys
import com.cybozu.labs.langdetect.*;

import net.arnx.jsonic.JSON;
import net.arnx.jsonic.JSONException;


import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;


import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.Headers;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;

class ExampleProgram {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

EveryDetector evr = new EveryDetector();
InetSocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress("localhost",7070);
HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(addr, 0);

MyHandler hndl = new MyHandler();
hndl.setDetector(evr);

MyHandlerExtractContent hnd2 = new MyHandlerExtractContent();
hnd2.setDetector(evr);

MyHandlerDetectLanguage hnd3 = new MyHandlerDetectLanguage();
hnd3.setDetector(evr);

server.createContext("/",hndl);
server.createContext("/extractcontent",hnd2);
server.createContext("/detectlanguage",hnd3);
server.setExecutor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
server.start();
System.out.println("Server is listening on port 7070" );


 }
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: are you trying to have the java program continue after you close your shell /window? please edit to clarify.

Comment: Java program does not continue after I close shell. That is main problem.

Comment: If you are running in linux you may use `nohup` command. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797050/how-to-run-process-as-background-and-never-die)

Comment: @VenkataRaju Does nohup command run after server reboot automatically?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you should run your program as a daemon. [Apache Commons Daemon](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/) has a [jsvc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/jsvc.html) tool that will do that for your program.

Note that your program has to be modified to either implement the `Daemon` interface or implement the `init`, `start`, `stop`, and `destroy` methods listed on the jsvc page.

Comment: Okay but do I need to restructure all my java app to run it as daemon?