# Unable to make nodejs work in background by "&"

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, ubuntu, background

I'm trying to start nodejs server in background:

```
nodejs  my_app.js &
```

But it shows the debug messages ("Starting at  0.0.0.0 ...") and then I disconnect from my server via ssh, it terminates. Why?

Comment: See this previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797050/how-to-run-process-as-background-and-never-die

Comment: @tschaible,  and still when I disconnect it terminates.

Comment: make use of PM2 or forever.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
nohup node my_app.js &
```

> http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/nohup.htm

Comment: and still when I disconnect it terminates.

Comment: May be your server is terminates due to some error in code. you can check the logs by redirecting them into a file **nohup node my_app.js 1>./out.log 2>./error.log &**

Answer (score 0):

Because with '&' your node process is still tied to the calling process (e.g. the Shell you typed this in). By killing your ssh-session you also kill all of its child processes.

The answer from @SourbhGupta is the one go with. `nohup` lets the child process ignore the hang up Signal. So, killing the calling process has no effect on its child process.

Answer (score 0):

Run it inside screen.

Screen process runs on background.

1.sudo apt-get install screen

2.screen (To start a screen process)

3.Run your service

4.node my_app.js (without & will do)

5.Ctrl+a+k to detach it.

For more information on screen-
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-screen-on-an-ubuntu-cloud-server