# Using Amazon EC2 Instance for Socket server

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I am working on a project in which I am using amazon EC2 instance as my TCP/IP socket server.I wrote my server code completely in C .I am able to login to EC2 instance via ssh and run my code. However I want to run that code always. I don't want run every time. how to do that? Do I need to put my C executable load at boot something like that? I have selected Ubuntu 14.04 as my server OS. Does amazon give permissions to use that instance as general computer so that I can put code at boot and restart?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797050/how-to-run-process-as-background-and-never-die

Comment: use the above linked answer or write a /etc/init.d script and make it run on boot with chkconfig