# Node.JS | Is it possible to move self to background?

Tags: javascript, node.js, console-application, background-process

Yes, I know [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797050/how-to-run-process-as-background-and-never-die) exists, but unfortunately it doesn't answer this specific question.

I am writing a Node.JS app to control multiple Steam trade bots and I am adding a terminal like interface to it. This will allow me to start and stop bots whenever. However is it possible to move the program into the background with just Node.JS code?

I would like to have a command like this:

```
function processCmd(cmd){
    var cmdArgs = cmd.split(" ");
    switch(cmdArgs[0]){
        case "bg":
            console.log("Moving to background...");
            // move program to background
            break;
    }
}
```

Is this possible? Or do I just have to restart the program manually?

Comment: You can move those tasks to child processes. http://www.andygup.net/node-js-moving-intensive-tasks-to-a-child-process/

Comment: The way my program currently works is it runs all in the one script. Therefore I can't just move anything to a child process as that is killed when I exit the main process. The idea is that I can type bg and logout of my SSH session.

Comment: `nohup node app.js &`

Comment: @robertklep the cheap way works too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way I found to keep it running was just use the `forever` package and allow access via an HTTP server port. Nevertheless thanks for your suggestions!