# Is there a way to run a python script and still be able to use my Ubuntu server?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, terminal, ubuntu-14.04

I have a server I lease from Digital Ocean. I access it using Putty. I want to run my python script in the background so that I can still do other things on the machine. What is a terminal command I can use to have it run in the background so that I can still use the machine?

Random information you might need:

-Using Ubuntu 14.04

-Python3.4 script

-My favorite dessert is cheesecake (buy me cheesecake)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: [How do I run a Python script in the background](http://askubuntu.com/questions/175751/how-do-i-run-a-python-script-in-the-background-and-restart-it-after-a-crash)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run process as background and never die?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797050/how-to-run-process-as-background-and-never-die)

Comment: Depending on the use case, you might consider using `nohup [script] &` or `tmux`/`screen`

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick answers. I'll check out those links and see if they help.

Comment: Just use & after your call

Comment: He didn't ask to run it forever - just has one console and wants to be able to do other things, too.  "&" is the easiest answer.

Comment: @Simon creating a subshell with `&` won't work, if the OP wants the script to keep on running even when the parent shell gets closed (though this is not specified). One should combine `nohup` and `&` to create a daemon processes.

Comment: What's to stop you running another putty window?

Comment: I think opening a 2nd Putty window works. Not sure why I didn't try that sooner. Would still be nice to know how to run things in the background, though. Just for the sake of knowing.

Comment: Other options would be `screen` or `tmux`...

Answer (score 1):

It's more of a unix/linux question than python, but you can do it in a couple of different ways:

```
% python myprogram.py &
```

The "&" says to run it in the background.

If you forgot, and just ran it, then you can type "^z" (control-Z) to suspend your program, then type:

```
% bg
```

To start it running again in the background.  And, just for fun, "fg" would put it back in the foreground.  You can have many processes running in the background - if you're doing more than one, you can use "%n" to explicitly say which one (i.e. "bg" and "bg %1" would both work, if you only had one background job), and for more fun, if you have multiple jobs running in the background:

```
% jobs
```

Will list them for you.

Comment: This answer was nice, because it helped expand my baby Linux knowledge, but I still can't use my terminal after running program with these commands. :(

Comment: Well, I use PuTTY from Windows to connect to my linux servers, and unless your host (Digital Ocean) is somehow prohibiting it, that's how it's done.  Control-Z might not work well through PuTTY (never tried it), but starting something with the "&" at the end of the line certainly should.

Comment: I'll try it again. Thanks for the help. :>