# How to keep a GlassFish server's domain active while disconnected from SSH to an EC2 instance?

Tags: java, soap, amazon-ec2, glassfish

Recently I built a SOAP web service with Java, I have no problem to deploy it on my EC2 instance, while the SSH connection is on with Putty, the test link and WSDL link are both working fine.

But once I disconnected from SSH, those 2 links became unavailable right away, could anyone please let me know if there is a way to keep the GlassFish server alive all the time, without the need to connect with Putty and start-domain in GlassFish each time.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You have to start the server as a background process. Running it as a process within your interactive console will cause it to be killed once you exit/kill that console session. This has been asked countless times on here and I'm surprised you didn't find anything from searching before you asked this question. See this as an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797050/how-to-run-process-as-background-and-never-die

Comment: Actually I'm surprised GlassFish isn't starting as a service already. Please show the command you are using to start GlassFish.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.
There steps resolved my issue:
$ screen
$ glassfish4/bin/asadmin start-domain
Now I can disconnect but the server remains working.