# Docker Swarm Cluster: daemonize

Tags: docker, daemon, docker-swarm

I'm in the process of setting up a [Docker Swarm cluster](https://docs.docker.com/swarm/install-manual/)

Im on this step:

```
sudo docker daemon -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
```

However, it looks like it's not deamonizing it (the program is still holding the screen)

How do I daemonize it?

Comment: Try [`dockerd -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/)

Comment: no that didnt work :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you run the daemon as a background process using `nohup / &`, using your example:

```
sudo nohup docker daemon -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock &
```

> Note: `docker daemon` has been deprecated and this should be `dockerd` now.

This is no different than running any other Linux process in the background: [How to run process as background and never die?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797050/how-to-run-process-as-background-and-never-die/11856575#11856575)