# PHP script on FreeBSD start up

Tags: php, cron, freebsd

I have to run a PHP script as a service. Also it should be run on start up too (when a system crash/rebbot occurs). I tried with a cron job that runs once in a year. Once the cron triggered the process, I commented out it while running the process. But after a system reboot process stopped.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797050/how-to-run-process-as-background-and-never-die) also but after closing the terminal process got stopped. Also I am not sure it will run on start up or not? Following is my php script.

```
<?php 
   while (true) {
      $command = "php $cwd\artisan synchronizedb --ptype=2";
      exec($command);
   }
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run php script as daemon process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036654/run-php-script-as-daemon-process)

Comment: @Dekel it wont restart on a system crash. So I want it restart on system startup.

Comment: You may want to [read this about how FreeBSD startup scripts work](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=rc&sektion=8)

Answer (score 1):

[FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/) has a very nice tool called [daemon](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=daemon&sektion=8) you could just create a simple script like this

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "starting XYZ"
daemon -r /path/to/your/script
```

The `-r`  option, Supervise and restart the program if it has been terminated.

Later you have some options

1. Add the script to [rc.local](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=rc.local&sektion=8), edit the file `/etc/rc.local`
2. Create a cron that runs only on reboot:

   ```
   @reboot  root /path/to/your/script
   ```
3. Put your script on `/usr/local/etc/rc.d` just chmod+x

The cron `@reboot` could be the easiest one.