# Deploy Create-React-App on Nginx

Tags: nginx, deployment, create-react-app

I'm attempting to deploy my `create-react-app` SPA on a Digital Ocean droplet with Ubuntu 14.04 and Nginx. Per the static server [deployment instructions](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#deployment), I can get it working when I run `serve -s build -p 4000`, but the app comes down as soon as I close the terminal. It is not clear to me from the `create-react-app` repo readme how to keep it running forever, similar to something like [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever).

Without running `serve`, I get Nginx's 502 Bad Gateway error.

Nginx Conf

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name app.mydomain.com;
  root /srv/app-name;
  index index.html index.htm index.js;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/node-app.access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/node-app.error.log;
  location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|pdf|txt|tar|wav|bmp|rtf|js|flv|swf|html|htm|svg)$ {
    root   /srv/app-name/build;
  }
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just serve the static files directly using nginx?

Comment: I would but... it is not working. Getting 502 error, not clear why. Error logs only show "111: connection refused"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run process as background and never die?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797050/how-to-run-process-as-background-and-never-die)

Answer (score 98, accepted):

One of the major benefits of React (and Create React App) is that you don't need the overhead of running a Node server (or proxying to it with Nginx); you can serve the static files directly.

From the [Deployment documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/) you've linked to, Create React App describes what to do:

> `npm run build` creates a `build` directory with a production build of your app. Set up your favorite HTTP server so that a visitor to your site is served `index.html`, and requests to static paths like `/static/js/main.<hash>.js` are served with the contents of the `/static/js/main.<hash>.js` file.

In your case, run `npm run build` to create the `build/` directory and then make the files available in a location Nginx can access them. Your build is probably best done on your local machine and then you can securely copy the files across to your server (via SCP, SFTP etc).  You *could* run `npm run build` on your server, but if you do, resist the temptation to directly serve the `build/` directory as the next time you run a build, clients could receive an inconsistent set of resources whilst you're building.

Whichever build method you choose, once your `build/` directory is on your server, then check its permissions to ensure Nginx can read the files and configure your `nginx.conf` like so:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name app.mydomain.com;
  root /srv/app-name;
  index index.html;
  # Other config you desire (TLS, logging, etc)...
  location / {
    try_files $uri /index.html;
  }
}
```

This configuration is based upon your files being in `/srv/app-name`.  In short, the `try_files` directive attempts to load CSS/JS/images etc first and for all other URIs, loads the `index.html` file in your build, displaying your app.

For note, you should be deploying using HTTPS/SSL to serve it rather than with insecure HTTP on port 80.  [Certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/) provides automatic HTTPS for Nginx with free Let's Encrypt certificates, if the cost or process of obtaining a certificate would otherwise hold you back.

Comment: location / {
    try_files $uri /index.html;
  }  That helped man. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was hosting NextJS as main app on `/` and wanted to host CRA on `/admin` route. Here is what I did:

- serve CRA through custom express server
- change `hostname` in package.json
- add `basename` to `/admin` for react-router
- define the following proxy pass:

```
location / {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
}
location /admin {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
}
location /admin/ {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:3001/;
}
```

Related articles:

- [CRA Deployment](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment)
- [React-Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter/basename-string)
- [Multiple SPAs](https://chrysanthium.com/multiple-spa-paths-gateway)
- [Another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54340240/create-react-app-build-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token)