# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' When using create-react-app develop mode

Tags: html, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, create-react-app

im getting this error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
" when using CRA development server. Usually clearing cache and reloading helps. How can i fix that?
Link repo in which my problem occurs:
https://github.com/MaciejWiatr/Cookup/tree/develop

Comment: Maybe it can help:
<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54340240/create-react-app-build-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token>

Comment: Already tried this one and it didnt work :(

Comment: Can you provide a stack trace of the error?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, it seems that I've figured it out. It was all serviceWorker's fault. I've added the following snippet and everything started working fine

```js
if (!process.env.NODE_ENV || process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
    // dev code
    serviceWorker.unregister();
} else {
    // production code
    serviceWorker.register();
}
```