# when deploying create-react-app getting Unexpected token '<'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, web-deployment, create-react-app

I'm trying to deploy create-react-app using express.js.  I'm also using client side routing (react-router-dom v5) with basename **my-app**.

When I refresh page the following urls via browser:

- https://my-website.com/my-app/
- https://my-website.com/my-app/something -> everything works fine.

but when I refresh page with url https://my-website.com/my-app/:type/:id (for example: https://my-website.com/my-app/polar/12345.)

I'm getting following error:

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'**  --> browser tries to load /js/chunk.js and /js/main.chunk.js files requesting these urls:

- https://my-website.com/my-app/polar/12345/static/js/chunk.js
- https://my-website.com/my-app/polar/12345/static/js/main.chunk.js

instead of these:

- https://mywebsite.com/my-app/static/js/chunk.js
- https://mywebsite.com/my-app/static/js/main.chunk.js . -> Files are located at these urls.

here is my express server file:

```js
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

const root = path.join(__dirname, 'build');

app.use(express.static(root));

app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
  console.log('requested!', req.originalUrl);
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(9000, () => {
  console.log('App is running on port 9000');
});
```

I'm deploying app via docker file into kubernetes cluster on AWS. Pages are served via nginx ingress controller.

**Where should be the problem ?**

Comment: Your question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54375564/12738262)

Comment: @EnochChejieh I tried it. Id didnt help me.