# Manifest error in react app when using build for deployment

Tags: node.js, reactjs, deployment, build

I'm running build for a react app and using the index.html file path on my node server. Everything is working fine but on routes where I am using slugs are giving errors:

path is like: /blog/:id

/blog is working as it should but

/blog/someID is throwing this error in console and browser just gives a white screen.

[image]

Things are working fine in my react app locally. I believe it is an issue with the build process.

I have not seen this error before. I've used this process multiple times and it works fine but this time it is throwing some error. Can someone guide me why it is throwing this error?

Thank you.

Comment: Take look at this if you already haven't. This may help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54340240/create-react-app-build-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token

Comment: I do not have any homepage thing in my package.json. Morever, this error is only coming on pages where I've used /:slug in react router. Other pages like "/", "/aboutus" are working fine.

Comment: Not that answer. I was referring to the accepted answer actually.