# How do I debug `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' `? React/Webpack/GithubPages issue

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, webpack, github-pages

Chrome tools in production throw `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'` when I load my React App hosted on Github pages. I just about lost count with how many posts and pages of documentation I read through the past 5 days trying to debug this. I think this can possibly be a lazy loading issue for all I know despite the vague error. I included snippets of relevant code below. Please help.

**Error Message**

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

**Screenshot of console**
[image: Error Message]

**What Error points to in source tab of chrome tools**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png">
        <script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
        <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>

        <title>App Name</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/app-name/#/dist/favicon.png">
        <link href="/app-name/#/dist/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="/app-name/#/dist/bundle.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Webpack.common.js**

```js
const path = require('path')

// const modeBool = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'

const tempDir = __dirname + '/index.html'
const tempFileName = 'index.html'

const outputPath = path.join(__dirname, './dist')
// const outputPublicPath = modeBool ? '/app-name/dist' : '/'

const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')
const HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const HTMLWebpackPluginConfig = new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
  template: tempDir,
  filename: tempFileName,
  inject: 'head',
  favicon: "favicon.png"
})


module.exports = {

  entry: path.resolve( __dirname, 'src', 'index.jsx' ),

  output: {
    path: outputPath,
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/app-name/#/dist/'
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.jsx?$/, exclude: /(node_modules)/, 
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: { presets: ['@babel/env', '@babel/react'] }
        },
      }, 
      { test: /\.css$/i, 
        use: [ 
          {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            options: { publicPath: '../' }
          }, 
          'css-loader'
        ],
      }
    ]
  },

  // optimization: {
  //   splitChunks: { chunks: "all" }
  // },

  plugins: [ 
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
    HTMLWebpackPluginConfig,
  ],

  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".css", "*"]
  },

  performance: {
    hints: false
  },

  stats: {
    errorDetails: true,
    warnings: true,
    colors: true,
  },


};
```

**Webpack.prod.js**

```js
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge')
const common = require('./webpack.common.js')


module.exports = merge( common, {

  mode: "production",

  devtool: "source-map",

} )
```

**Package.json**

```js
{
  "name": "app-name",
  "version": "1.2.2",
  "description": "XXXXXXX",
  "main": "index.jsx",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d dist",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js",
    "start": "webpack serve --config webpack.dev.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "XXXXXXXXX"
  },
  "author": "Dan XXXXX",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "XXXXXXXX"
  },
  "homepage": ".",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "gh-pages": "^3.1.0",
    "googleapis": "^64.0.0",
    "inline-source-map": "^0.6.2",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.3.2",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.1.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.0",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "webpack": "^5.2.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  }

}
```

**Index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png">

  <!-- youtube video API -->
  <script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
  <!-- youtube data API -->
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>

  <!-- SO post rec 3 -->
  <!-- <script type="text/babel" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.24/browser.min.js"></script> -->
  <!-- SO post rec 4 -->
  <!-- <base href="/" /> -->

  <title>App Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Component with lazy loaded import**

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

import LocationControls from '../controls/LocationControls'
import MusicControls from '../controls/MusicControls'

import { tracks, locations } from '../misc/data.js'

const importDataAPI = () => import('../../utils/YTDataAPI.js')
const importMediaAPI = () => import('../../utils/YTVideoAPI.js')

export const locationURL = React.createContext(null)
export const musicURL = React.createContext(null)


const Player = () => {
  const [ currentCountry, setCountry ] = useState('France')

  useEffect( () => {
    importDataAPI()
    importMediaAPI()
  }, [])

  // This method calls our API to load a new video
  const mediaAPILoader = ( vidId, player ) => { 
    try {
      window[ player ]?.loadVideoById({ videoId: vidId }) 
    } catch( error ) {
      console.log( `The following error has occured ${ error }. Restarting application. ` )
      window.history.go()
    }
  } 


  return (
    <div className="player-component-container">

      <musicURL.Provider value={ currentCountry }>
        <MusicControls trackLists={ tracks } loadFunc={ mediaAPILoader } />
      </musicURL.Provider>

      <div id="unclickable-overlay"></div>
      <div id="musicPlayer"></div> {/* our music embedded player */}
      <div id="locationPlayer"></div>  {/* our location embedded player */}

      <LocationControls locationURLs={ locations } updateCurr={ setCountry } loadFunc={ mediaAPILoader } />

    </div>
  ) 

}

export default Player
```

ALL help is appreciated.

Comment: Please post the complete error message, including the line number in which file it occurs. -- That error can be when JS is expecting a json and getting some html instead... It also can be many things. -- I removed the strange $20 offer which is ot relevant.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I included your recommendations, I greatly appreciate you looking into this as well! I ready to learn the reason behind the vague error

Comment: Maybe [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54340240/create-react-app-build-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token) helps?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette unfortunately not, I already tried the recommended `package.json` fix there. And to apply the `node.js` solution requires complete rework of my entry

Comment: Might this be a babel compilation or webpack issue?