# How can I configure my Nginx file to correctly display my React app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx, create-react-app

I've got my build folder on my server and I assume I've correctly configured nginx to be able to see it (I copied the config from [Deploy Create-React-App on Nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46880853/deploy-create-react-app-on-nginx)), but I still get a 404 page when I try to navigate to it. Is my nginx file just not configured right? I can't figure out what could be causing this problem.

I've tried following [Deploy Create-React-App on Nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46880853/deploy-create-react-app-on-nginx) exactly, changing things to match my own server name etc. when appropriate.

This is the section I've added to my config file:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name xxx.net www.xxx.net;
        root /var/www/xxx.net/html/build;
        index index.html;
        location /news {
        try_files $uri /index.html;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why you have /news in the location block?

Comment: Someone told me to add that it if I wanted it to show up at www.xxx.net/news

Comment: Try removing that, I am not sure why you need that...

Comment: If I remove that I think it'll conflict with my main site on the domain, though, right?

Comment: Oh... Then in your application which is at path yoursite/news you have to specify base path I guess.