# NGINX With React Build

Tags: reactjs, nginx

I put the files of my React build in: `root/website.com/site/public`.

My `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    root /root/website.com/site/public/;
    server_name 00.000.00.000; 
    index index.html index.htm;
    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

I get a bad gateway error when I go to my ip address. Do I need to run `npm start` to get my `index.html` to show up?

For some reason when I run `npm start` it searches for `index.html` in `/site/src` then if I change the name of `public` to `src` it searches in `site/public`.

Comment: try to use the root directory of your application if that may help. I got the idea from this. https://codeburst.io/how-to-setup-nginx-for-react-a504f38f95ed or at least the react app is built based on this https://medium.com/@timmykko/deploying-create-react-app-with-nginx-and-ubuntu-e6fe83c5e9e7

edit: found a similar question here and there's an answer :D hope this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46880853/deploy-create-react-app-on-nginx

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That did not work for me though.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46880853/deploy-create-react-app-on-nginx found this :) please try this out :D and check your permissions as well :)

Comment: Thanks for your help! I will try these and post if anything works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `/root/website.com/site/public` was unreachable by nginx apparently. Changed it to the typical `/var/www/website/site/public` and moved my build file there and it worked.