# How to fix page reload problem of live server react project if I host my project

Tags: reactjs, internal-server-error

I host mine react project to Namecheap server. It's working fine, but when I go to about or other pages and reload this page the page is gone and it shows me a 404 error. why did I get a 404 error and how to fix it?

Comment: You need to configure your server to redirect your request to index.html instead of 404 page.  
nginx example:
` try_files $uri /index.html;`

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. Do you have any usefull resources for this issue?

Comment: try this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47505427/16116506

Answer (score 0):

Create a .htaccess file on your root folder and paste the following code

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
      RewriteBase /
      RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
      RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
    </IfModule>
```