# AWS CodeDeploy stuck at Application start

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline

I have a `nodejs` app that i need to run on an EC2 host. The pipe is passing file and if i run it manually it works. But at the `ApplicationStart` phase it gets stuck in `pending` state. My start-server.sh is this:

```
grunt build && cd ./dist && http-server -p 9000 > /dev/null 2> /dev/null < /dev/null &
```

The server itself starts and it is working but for some reason the deploy step keeps waiting for it. If i run it manually it starts properly as a detached process. Any solutions/workarounds?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `&` to the end of your command. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797050/how-to-run-process-as-background-and-never-die) a post with a number of suggestions.