# How to run program as daemon?

Tags: daemon, fluentd

I have configured [fluentd](https://www.fluentd.org/download) using [fluentd-ui](https://docs.fluentd.org/v0.12/articles/fluentd-ui) on debian machine. How do I start it in background without the GUI?

Comment: [Documentation](https://docs.fluentd.org/v0.12/articles/command-line-option), quote: ` -d, --daemon PIDFILE             daemonize fluent process`

Comment: Hope this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797050/how-to-run-process-as-background-and-never-die

Answer (score 0):

In your `/etc/systemd/system` you can create a file and define the service:

**fluentd.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Fluentd
Documentation=http://www.fluentd.org/
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/bin/fluentd -d /run/fluentd.pid
PIDFile=/run/fluentd.pid
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```