# How to detach process in Ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, telegram

I'm running a chatbot on Ubuntu server on Amazon EC2 instance. I want to be able to run the python3 program even after closing the pUTTY window. So far I've tried 'Ctrl+a, d' as well as 'Ctrl+z, bg'. However both methods did not seem to work after closing the pUTTY window. I referenced the following youtube video:

Would really appreciate any help!
[image: Chatbot Output]
[image: Ubuntu Screen running python program]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run Node.js as a background process and never die?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797050/how-to-run-node-js-as-a-background-process-and-never-die)

Comment: There are no error messages sir. Apologies just starting out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the question is *"how to keep the python script running even after closing the putty"*

IMO, you can use 2 approaches here.

**Use nohup**
The unix command `nohup` can make your program run in background even after exiting the terminal.
You can run it like

```
nohup python3 LP_poolVol.py > /dev/null &
```

`nohup` will make the script running and the `&` at the end will make it in
background

**Make the script a service**

Run the script as a linux service which you can start and stop using the `systemctl`
You can create a service descriptor file `pool-vol.service` with contents similar to below.

```
[Unit]
Description=Pool Vol Service
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 <path-to>/LP_poolVol.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then copy this service file to `/etc/systemd/system/`. And then install it via the commands below

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable pool-vol.service
sudo systemctl start pool-vol
```

Now your app is running as a service. You can stop or restart it using the `systemctl` itself like

```
sudo systemctl start pool-vol
```